# The operation = and in will lead to different results in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about the difference in the operators `=` and `in`.

Previously I used operator `in` in most of cases, but I found it is not working in today's quiz. The question is as following:

> Query the customer_number from the orders table for the customer who has placed the largest number of orders.

It is guaranteed that exactly one customer will have placed more orders than any other customer.

The orders table is defined as follows:

```
| Column            | Type      |
|-------------------|-----------|
| order_number (PK) | int       |
| customer_number   | int       |
| order_date        | date      |
| required_date     | date      |
| shipped_date      | date      |
| status            | char(15)  |
| comment           | char(200) |
```

Sample Input

```
| order_number | customer_number | order_date | required_date | shipped_date | status | comment |
|--------------|-----------------|------------|---------------|--------------|--------|---------|
| 1            | 1               | 2017-04-09 | 2017-04-13    | 2017-04-12   | Closed |         |
| 2            | 2               | 2017-04-15 | 2017-04-20    | 2017-04-18   | Closed |         |
| 3            | 3               | 2017-04-16 | 2017-04-25    | 2017-04-20   | Closed |         |
| 4            | 3               | 2017-04-18 | 2017-04-28    | 2017-04-25   | Closed |         |
```

Sample Output

```
| customer_number |
|-----------------|
| 3               |
```

And my approach is:

```
select 
    customer_number 
    from orders  
    group by customer_number
    having count(*) in
(
select 
max(total)
from (
    select 
    count(*) as total 
    from orders  
    group by customer_number
) as d 
)
```

But it won't produce any result. If I replace the `in` with `=`, I can get what I would like. Could anyone explain this?

Comment: you have made the sql too complex. it could be done simple. just add order by count(*) and limit 1 will give you only one record  and also make order desc as you want the highest,

Comment: I think the behavior is related to the use of COUNT(*) in the HAVING clause.  As a test, try replacing COUNT(*) with SUM(1). Also test adding `COUNT(*) AS foo` to the select list, and referencing the alias foo in the HAVING clause.

Comment: The query runs as expected in MySql 5.5: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=2e89ad8f37dd17a6a782d44d851a0c84 It fails in MySql 5.6+

Comment: If you nest the IN subquery 1 level deeper it works up to version 5.7 too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=991f537c17e8d59dab55c250a1763583 but fails in 8.0

Comment: `It is guaranteed that exactly one customer will have placed more orders than any other customer.` on this basis , your query is massively over complicated

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for your suggestion. I just would like to make it general enough.

Comment: @AhmedSunny Thank you for your suggestion. I just would like to make it general enough. My focus is on why the results via = and in will be different.

Comment: Thank you @forpas. But I got a little bit confusing. Do you mean different version of MySQL will support different operations, like one version will support in while another will support =.

Comment: Thank you @spencer7593, but got a little bit confusion. Would you mind suggesting an answer below so that I can test it?

Comment: @QiangSuper yes, in version 5.5 everuthing worked as expected. It seems like a bug.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because I can't answer the question that was asked (i.e. I can't explain the observed behavior, let's leave room for someone that can.)  My comment is that the behavior may not be exclusively related to `IN` vs `=` . I think the behavior is also related to `COUNT(*)`.  My suggestion is to test the exact same query, but replace `HAVING COUNT(*) IN` with `HAVING SUM(1) IN` and see if the behavior is any different.  I suspect the query with SUM(1) will return expected results, which would lead us to conclude the behavior difference it's not entirely due to `IN` vs `=` .

Comment: @forpas. Thank you for your help. It makes sense to me. I think you can make a conclusion as the answer.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for your help. I will try and keep  you posted. I am wondering what is the difference between count(*) and sum(1)?

Comment: @QiangSuper actually there is no answer to the question *why it does not work*. It should work. As I mentioned in an earlier comment, this must be a bug.

Comment: @QiangSuper: the way i see it, the values returned by `COUNT(*)` and `SUM(1)` are equivalent; but I think the MySQL optimizer (that parses the SQL text and prepares an execution plna) sees them differently. I concur with forpas: the most likely explanation for the observed behavior is a *bug* in the MySQL optimizer introduced in version 5.6.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for your help. Great to learn something new.

Comment: @forpas Thank you for your insight. I appreciate it.